# Indenting sub-bullet points

Tags: sectioning, indentation, cv

I had seen the following resume in the net and wanted to replicate the same.
[image]
I tried out the following, but it does not seem to be working.

```
\section{Technical Skills}
\noindent\rule{\textwidth}{\hlinewidth}
\begin{innerlist}
\item \textbf{Languages} - [\textit{Proficient}] C, C++,Perl,Shell \\ 
            \hspace{25mm}- [\textit{Competent}] Java,Python,SQL
\item \textbf{Miscellaneous} :  Github, gdb , valgrind,
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the tabular environment to get the output like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{Technical Skills}

\noindent\begin{tabular}{ll}
 \textbf{Languages}& - \textbf{\textit{Proficient}} C, C++,Perl,Shell \\ 
        &- \textbf{\textit{Competent}} Java,Python,SQL\\
\textbf{Miscellaneous} : & Github, gdb , valgrind,
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Tech skilz:
\begin{itemize}
\item[Langs:]

\emph{Good:} Brainf*ck

\emph{OK:} INTERCAL

\item[Stuff:] MS-DOS, CRAY computers
\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```